# Google geocoder API results saving to an array -> problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-geocoder

I've got a problem with saving geocoder results to an array. I've got three text input fields and have to get the coordinates of the locations put in them. This works fine so far, but I don't know how to save those results to an array for later processing. It doesn't seem to work the normal way. Here's my code so far:

```
var addresses = [];
        var count = 0;
        var address;
        var results = [];
        var geocoderResults = [];

function startQuery() {
            while (count <= 2) {
                var address = document.getElementById("query_input" + count).value;
                addresses[count] = address; 
                alert (address); 
                getCoordsFromAddress(addresses[count]);
                count ++;
            }       

            alert(results[0] + ", " + results[1] + ", " + results[2]);
            count = 0;

        }

        function getCoordsFromAddress(addressString){
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var addressObj = {address:addressString};

            geocoder.geocode(addressObj, onGeocoderReady);
        }

        function onGeocoderReady(geocoderResults, status){

            var lat = geocoderResults[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = geocoderResults[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var formattedAddress = geocoderResults[0].formatted_address;
            var location =  lat+","+lng;
            alert(location);
            results[count] = location;

        }
```

so like this, I will get three alerts showing me the location names first and at the end of the workflow I will get three alerts showing me the three coordinates one after another instead of location/coords/location/coords... 
And it is not possible to save "location" to the array like I'm trying.
But what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help